# Is anyone using Sencha Touch for mobile development?

Tags: iphone, android, sencha-touch, extjs

We're evaluating Sencha Touch for mobile development. Has anyone used this yet (I realize that it's still in beta), and if so, what are its strengths / weaknesses? How does it compare to alternatives?

It certainly sounds compelling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm playing with [Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch/), I have a [project up at GitHub](http://github.com/artlung/ArtLung-Notes/). If you're comfortable with [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) it will be familiar. The [examples are impressive](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/) (requires WebKit browser). You might be interested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3031643/resources-frameworks-for-mobile-development-iphone-android-using-html5) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it only briefly. It looks very good and has a nice array of tools to make pseudo-native apps. One of the larger concerns is the licensing (the inclusion of ExtJS and the requirement to purchase a license to use the software). Now ExtJS and Sencha have merged - so I am unsure of what the impact will be. Also, as for alternatives, Sencha has merged in JQTouch (a primary alternative). See this [post](http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/06/14/ext-js-jqtouch-raphael-sencha/) for more information

Comment: yes, the licensing is definitely a concern. Thanks for the link - good info.

Comment: [Sencha person] The beta is under open source license - GPLv3. We will be adding a commercial trial and then when we release, a full-on commercial option. If you're ok releasing source code to users, or if you're not conveying your app outside your company then you're good with GPL, otherwise you'll need commercial. Although we're also planning to have some personal/non-profit etc. carveouts to make it easier for folks to use who are not doing full-on commercial development.

Comment: [Update] There is a commercial trial license in the latest beta 0.92

Comment: Commercial license is now free, as per: http://www.sencha.com/blog/2010/11/15/sencha-touch-1-0-ships-now-free/

Comment: Yes, Sencha Touch is and will remain free for both commercial and open source uses.

Answer (score 0):

I think currently it is only optimized for safari-browser. I tried in on Android Phone (HTC Magic, Android 1.6) and the examples didn't work.

but it is a beta of course....

Comment: Android 2.1 and above is our target. And for a good experience on Android, you really want to upgrade to 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Currently ,i'm using sencha-touch in my project and pretty easy to use and understand especially with the documentation that comes along with it . As compared other mobile fameworks whose documentation is limited